# content="width=device-width" is not scaling or adjusting items in html5 and css3

Tags: html, css

So I have the meta tag: 
meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no"

Yet whenever I resize the elements, it's not working. I'm using percentages in the width, but nothing's changing.

```
html, body {
background-color: #fff;
color: #555;
font-family: 'lato', 'arial', sans-serif;
font-weight: 300;
font-size: 20px;
text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: I will suggest you ignore the max and min scale size more like just try `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: That didn't fix it. Is it because my header image is an img src, and not a background-image to the header element?

Comment: I figured out the issue. Thanks y'all.